# Window on Gnome/Linux/Ubuntu was bad shown

Tags: linux, gnome, ubuntu-14.10

My window on Gnome is not correctly shown.

When moving a Gnome window, it is slow to moved.

My problem is shown in the image below:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think you need to have someone with a better grasp of the english language ask translate your question. Also I think this is not even close to the correct place to ask, try SuperUser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved ,i do reinistall gnome3
Command:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell
sudo apt-get purge ubuntu-gnome-desktop

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```